# Regex retrieve CN value JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to retrieve CN value using Regex.

The format is like below.

CN=ABC/OU=SAMPLE/O=SAMPLE

I only needed to use CN value from it.
And tried Regex as below.
But it didn't work.

Please would you let me know what was wrong and right way to use regex.

```
 function getMatch(str) {

var m = str.match(/^[A-Z]{1,2}[=]{1}[a-z0-9]+/);
return m[1];
 }
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `^[A-Z]{1,2}[=]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+` (so that the `CN` value could also contain uppercase letters as it does in the example)?

Comment: Oh thanks I missed about that. Now I've succeeded with the code in the answer though. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
CN=([^\/$]*)
```

where group 1 will get you the cn value

Explanation:

```
[^\/$]*
```

1. It ensures that it will capture everything untill the next slash /
   or $ ensures incase cn comes at the end of the string it will also
   get match

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/5)

```js
const regex = /CN=([^\/$]*)/g;
const str = `CN=ABC/OU=SAMPLE/O=SAMPLE`;
let m;

if((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```